# WP current category - strange behaviour

Tags: wordpress, categories

I've use this code:

```
$current_id = get_query_var('name');
echo $current_cat;

$category_id = get_cat_ID($current_cat);
echo $category_id;
```

to get current page category number. Everything is working fine but category with dashed name (like "main-news" have value 0.

Is there a solution (except changing name to mainNews) to fix that?

Comment: Don't use `get_query_var`, as it won't support more if permalinks change. Try to get current category using `$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);`.

Comment: Hi! Thank You for reply. When I use Your solution and var_dump( $categories ) I'm getting: array (size=0) empty :-/

Comment: Just try defining `global $post;` above the code.

Comment: Hello again :-)
The code:      
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
var_dump( $categories );

still gives my an empty array... :-o

Comment: Still not getting anything ? You're visiting a page or category page ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29797/discussion-between-rikesh-and-cachaito)